# How to get xyz cordinates of forge-viewer onClick event?

Tags: autodesk, viewer, forge, xyz

I am following this (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forge-viewer-pjyarf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) link to get the xyz cordinates of viewer onclick event in Angular.I cant get the viewer properly. Please help to get the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit() {

```
this.mainFunction();
```

}

mainFunction(){
this.viewerOptions = {

```
initializerOptions: {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: (
      onGetAccessToken: (token: string, expire: number) => void
    ) => {
      const expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
      onGetAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, expireTimeSeconds);
    },
    api: 'derivativeV2',
    enableMemoryManagement: true,
  },
  onViewerInitialized: (args: ViewerInitializedEvent) => {
    args.viewerComponent.DocumentId = DOCUMENT_URN;
    this.viewer=args.viewer;

  },
  
};
```

}
selectionChanged(e){

```
const state = this.viewer.viewerState.getState({ viewport: true });
const globalOffset = this.viewer.model.myData.globalOffset

const currentPosition = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray( state.viewport.eye );
const originPosition = currentPosition.clone().add( globalOffset );
  console.log("hiiihhaaaaaa:",originPosition);
```

}